# R ggplot2 histogram and facet_grid fill out of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to generate a facet_grid with histograms I ended up with some bars having the fill out of the bar, usually filling the whole plot.

Here I append an example code that generates the issue:

```
p<- ggplot(test, aes(x=value,fill=Tipo)) + geom_bar() + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1, colour = "black")

p + facet_grid(variable ~ Bloque) + ggtitle("Aroma")+xlab("PGA [g]")+ylab("Frecuencia")
```

And the test data (csv) is this:

```
"","X","FID","Shape..","Id","Area","Nombre","MegaRM","Estado","Distribuci","Ancho","L","Ld","Dd","H","L2","Ldiagonal","Ang","Volumen","Longitude","Latitude","H_L","Nombre_vie","Tipo","ORIG_FID","Ruiz2014","Flexura","Bloque","variable","value"
"111",111,197,"Point",0,2154209.498,"R7","Sí",NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,458597.0194,7862435.389,0,"R3N","Deslizamiento compuesto",197,0.229818,"Soga","Bloque colgante","PGAv, Ambraseys & Douglas (2003)",0.463383
```

Does anyone has any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide your data using `dput(test)`?  You can paste the results in the post; this will make it easer to answer the question.  Also, `test` should be a minimal data set to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use both `geom_bar` and `geom_histogram` here.  That is causing the issue you are seeing.  If you want a histogram, use `geom_histogram` and get rid of the `geom_bar` layer.